# Pylint logging checker doesn't recognize logging module-Level functions

Tags: python, logging, pylint

Can someone help on how to make pylint recognize logger subclass

Eg., `logging.error("{}".format(APPLE))`   works fine when the

```
logging-format-style=new
logging-modules=format
```

are set in pylintrc. But, for the same config,

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.error("{}".format(APPLE))
```

pylint throws error  :

```
Use lazy % formatting in logging functions (logging-format-interpolation)
```

Answer (score 0):

A linter is there to tell you when you aren't doing things quite right. That's why it's flagging up that call - you're not using best practice, which is lazy evaluation of the message using % formatting. Using `logger.error("%s", APPLE)` would avoid that linter complaint.